# cron job timing

Tags: cron

I would like to start cron job at 9:30 and then work every 5 minutes and then stop at 16:30 everday. Is this kind of scheduling possible in one or do I  need two cron jobs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think something along the lines of:

```
30/5 9-16 * * *  /usr/bin/script_to_run.sh
```

See the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for details of timing syntax. I suggest testing this with a script that logs the time it runs at to a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Cron ran at: " `date` >> /var/log/crontimetest.log
```

Comment: i was surprised to see "30/5" used, so i looked at the cron source code, specifically entry.c, which parses each line of a crontab. in the function get_range(), it checks to see if the character after the first number (30 in this example) is a '-' or not. if it's not, the '/' is never seen. this is a bug; it ought to have printed a warning (or an error message) of the form, "'/' is only meaningful following a * or a n-m range". sorry folks!

Answer (score 7):

you'll need three crontab entries:

```
30-55/5 9 * * * /usr/bin/script-to-run.sh
*/5 10-15 * * * /usr/bin/script-to-run.sh
0-30/5 16 * * * /usr/bin/script-to-run.sh
```

please do not blame linux, or bsd, or me, for the bizarre and useless syntax of crontab entries. this was invented at AT&T Bell Labs, and later standardized as part of POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need three jobs:

```
 */5 10-15 * * * yourjob
 0,5,10,15,20,25,30 16 * * * yourjob
 30,35,40,45,50,55 9 * * * yourjob
```